# Add in wordpress js with wp_enqueue_script()

Tags: wordpress

I have a JS script and I want to connect it with `wp_enqueue_script` in my `functions.php`. The script is connected with success, but the problem is that my script contains a PHP code.

When I try to connect js script I get an error and my page doesn't work. My code works if I insert it in `foote.php`, but I want to change the location.

So, is it possible to connect my script with `wp_enqueue_script`, taking into account that I have a small php code? What is the solution?

Comment: You can't put PHP in a `.js` file...

Comment: @Ty Bailey what could be the problem, if my script works  in footer, but when i change the location  appeared errors?

Comment: Does your script require jQuery or some other library? It might be referencing a script that is loaded after yours is loaded, in which the scope would be off.  Try using the 3rd parameter (dependencies) to load it properly. So like `wp_enqueue_script('script-name', 'script-location', array('jquery'));`